# Attrchange Library not working within .each()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of items in HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="pagination_element current">1</li>
    <li class="pagination_element">2</li>
    <li class="pagination_element">3</li>
    <li class="pagination_element">4</li>
    <li class="pagination_element">5</li>
</ul>
```

under certain external conditions, the "current" class will change between the various LI tags. I'm shooting to be able to observe these items anytime their class changes, and then pinpoint which one is "current" at any given time.

I'm using a library called attrchange (http://meetselva.github.io/) which should be able to execute a callback function anytime the class changes.

Here's my JS:

```
jQuery('.pagination_element').each(function() {

    console.log(jQuery(this));

    jQuery(this).attrchange({
        trackValues: true,
        callback: function (event) {
            console.log('here!');
            console.log('Attribute Name: ' + event.attributeName + ' Prev Value: ' + event.oldValue + ' New Value: ' + event.newValue);
        }
    });

});
```

The console.log(jQuery(this)); is working, and each LI is output to the console. The part that isn't working is the attrchange(). When the "current" class changes on an LI, nothing is logged to the console.

I have included jQuery, jQueryUI, attrchange.js, and attrchange_ext.js in that order, and those all load successfully.

Comment: It will help people help you if you update the question with a **runnable** [mcve] using stack snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('.pagination_element').attrchange({
        trackValues: true,
        callback: function (event) {
            console.log('here!');
            console.log('Attribute Name: ' + event.attributeName + ' Prev Value: ' + event.oldValue + ' New Value: ' + event.newValue);
        }
});
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/112g/pen/YxBzgp)